# Add Rows to Dataset based on existing values for missing years in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am currently working on visualizing formula one standings using the 'ergast' API in R using jsonlite. I have gathered data from all f1 standings since 1950 and cleaned up the data as shown in the picture of the dataset. I have already cumulated the data to determine for every year how many seasons the given driver has won. I now want to transform the dataset in a way that I have for every year, and for every driver, the `cum_seasons_won` so, e.g., in the first row or the first season (1950), `cum_seasons_won` should be for every driver in the dataset (except Nino Farina) 0. Another example would be in the last row: there should still be a value for, i.e., Juan Fangio with the value of five since he has won 5 championships to this day.

[image: Demo Data]

Any Help is greatly appreciated. Also, dplyr solutions and syntax would be preferred, but everything that gets me on the right track is helpful.

(Excuse the title, I don't know what the transformation I need to perform is called)

This is the dput output to reproduce the dataset:

```r
structure(list(full_name = c("Nino Farina", "Juan Fangio", "Alberto Ascari", 
"Alberto Ascari", "Juan Fangio", "Juan Fangio"), season_year = structure(c(-7305, 
-6940, -6575, -6209, -5844, -5479), class = "Date"), season_won = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), cum_seasons_won = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    full_name = c("Alberto Ascari", "Juan Fangio", "Nino Farina"
    ), .rows = structure(list(3:4, c(2L, 5L, 6L), 1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: My question is do you want it so that the maximum sum is the number present for every year? Or do you want their wins to increase over time? (i.e. cum_seasons_won for Alberto would be 2 for both rows, or like it currently is except continuously increasing for the total number of wins for Alberto). Also please include an extract of the data using `dput(head(my_data))`

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: @HanselPalencia, I want to keep the increasing part; basically, all data there should stay the same. Additionally, for every driver, for every season,  if they didn't win a championship before a 0. For the seasons, they haven't won after they won a championship, the max value. So to keep it simple I think your second suggestion.

Comment: moritz, thank you for editing in the sample data. In Stack questions, code fences must be on lines of their own, so your edit of `\`\`\`structure(...` needed to be changed to `\`\`\`\nstructure(...`, and same for the closing fence. I made an edit, hope that's okay. (Without doing that, the first line of code is not shown in the rendered page.)

Comment: @r2evans Yes i figured thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### example data

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("Nino","Juan","Alberto","Alberto","Juan"),
                 year = 1950:1954,
                 season_won = rep(1,5))
```

Result:

```
     name year season_won
1    Nino 1950          1
2    Juan 1951          1
3 Alberto 1952          1
4 Alberto 1953          1
5    Juan 1954          1
```

###### calculate cumulative wins

```
library(dplyr)

# for each driver, calculate cumulative win sums
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(cum_seasons_won = row_number()) %>%  # or: cum_seasons_won = cumsum(season_won)
  ungroup()
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  name     year season_won cum_seasons_won
  <chr>   <int>      <dbl>           <int>
1 Nino     1950          1               1
2 Juan     1951          1               1
3 Alberto  1952          1               1
4 Alberto  1953          1               2
5 Juan     1954          1               2
```

###### calculate cumulative wins ánd add rows to complete all years for all drivers

Since you've asked for this in the title of the question:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  
  # create missing rows, set season_won = 0
  complete(name, year, fill=list(season_won=0)) %>%
  
  # for each driver, calculate cumulative win sums
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(cum_seasons_won = cumsum(season_won)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  
  # optional: order by year, driver
  arrange(year, name)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 15 × 4
   name     year season_won cum_seasons_won
   <chr>   <int>      <dbl>           <dbl>
 1 Alberto  1950          0               0
 2 Juan     1950          0               0
 3 Nino     1950          1               1
 4 Alberto  1951          0               0
 5 Juan     1951          1               1
 6 Nino     1951          0               1
 7 Alberto  1952          1               1
 8 Juan     1952          0               1
 9 Nino     1952          0               1
 [...]
```